# ListView in RecyclerView doesn't recycle

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I made a RecyclerView with CardView. And CardView contains a TextView and ListView. TextView recycles well, but ListView's items are all same as I put last. How can I fix this?

- I'm using custom list view to fix problem CardView doesn't spread whole listView items.

Here are my codes.

```
recyclerview adapter:

public class NoticeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoticeAdapter.NoticeViewHolder>{
private ArrayList<String> noticeTypes;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> noticeTitles;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> noticeDates;

public NoticeAdapter() {
    noticeTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    noticeTitles = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    noticeDates = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
}

public void addNoticeSet(String noticeType, ArrayList<String> noticeTitle, ArrayList<String> noticeDate) {
    noticeTypes.add(noticeType);
    noticeTitles.add(noticeTitle);
    noticeDates.add(noticeDate);
}

@Override
public NoticeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notice_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new NoticeViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NoticeViewHolder noticeViewHolder, int i) {
    NoticeListAdapter noticeListAdapter = new NoticeListAdapter();
    noticeViewHolder.lv_noticeList.setAdapter(noticeListAdapter);

    String noticeType = noticeTypes.get(i);
    noticeViewHolder.tv_noticeType.setText(noticeType);
    noticeViewHolder.tv_noticeType.setPaintFlags(noticeViewHolder.tv_noticeType.getPaintFlags() | Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG);

    for(int m=0; m<5; m++)
        noticeListAdapter.addNoticeSet(noticeTitles.get(i).get(m),noticeDates.get(i).get(m));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return noticeTypes.size();
}

public static class NoticeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tv_noticeType;
    protected NoticeListView lv_noticeList;

    public NoticeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_noticeType = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_noticeType);
        lv_noticeList = (NoticeListView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.lv_noticeList);
    }
  }
}
```

custom list view adapter:

```
    public class NoticeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> noticeTitles;
    private ArrayList<String> noticeDates;

    public NoticeListAdapter() {
        noticeTitles = new ArrayList<>();
        noticeDates = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNoticeSet(String noticeTitle, String noticeDate) {
        noticeTitles.add(noticeTitle);
        noticeDates.add(noticeDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return noticeTitles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
        HashMap<String, String> noticeSet = new HashMap<>();
        noticeSet.put(noticeTitles.get(position), noticeDates.get(position));
        return noticeSet;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int pos = position;
        final Context context = parent.getContext();

        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noticelist_row, parent, false);
            TextView noticeTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_noticeTitle);
            TextView noticeDate = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_noticeDate);

            noticeTitle.setText(noticeTitles.get(position));
            noticeDate.setText(noticeDates.get(position));
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

custom list view :

```
    public class NoticeListView extends ListView {
    public NoticeListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NoticeListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public NoticeListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

cardview xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/cv_notice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_noticeType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.rb16.mainpage.NoticeListView
                    android:id="@+id/lv_noticeList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                    android:overScrollFooter="@android:color/transparent"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

how I put itmes in main activity:

```
private void setNoticeCard() {

    //noticeTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    //noticeDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    //noticeAdapter = NoticeAdapter();

    noticeTitle.add("1");
    noticeTitle.add("1");
    noticeTitle.add("1");
    noticeTitle.add("1");
    noticeTitle.add("1");

    noticeDate.add("2015-05-31");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-32");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-33");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-34");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-35");

    noticeAdapter.addNoticeSet("Notice1", noticeTitle, noticeDate);
    noticeTitle.clear();
    noticeDate.clear();

    noticeTitle.add("2");
    noticeTitle.add("2");
    noticeTitle.add("2");
    noticeTitle.add("2");
    noticeTitle.add("2");

    noticeDate.add("2016-07-08");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-30");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-30");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-30");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-30");

    noticeAdapter.addNoticeSet("Notice2", noticeTitle, noticeDate);
    noticeTitle.clear();
    noticeDate.clear();

    noticeTitle.add("3");
    noticeTitle.add("3");
    noticeTitle.add("3");
    noticeTitle.add("3");
    noticeTitle.add("3");

    noticeDate.add("2015-05-30");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-30");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-30");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-30");
    noticeDate.add("2015-05-30");

    noticeAdapter.addNoticeSet("Notice3", noticeTitle, noticeDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating ArrayList of String of both notice title and notice date. Create a class of NoticeDetails.

```
public class NoticeDetail {

String notice_name;
String notice_date;
String notice_title;

public String getNotice_name() {
    return notice_name;
}

public void setNotice_name(String notice_name) {
    this.notice_name = notice_name;
}

public String getNotice_date() {
    return notice_date;
}

public void setNotice_date(String notice_date) {
    this.notice_date = notice_date;
}

public String getNotice_title() {
    return notice_title;
}

public void setNotice_title(String notice_title) {
    this.notice_title = notice_title;
}
```

}

Now create arraylist of this class and everytime before adding the datat create new object of the class and set the data to the class and at the end add the class into the arraylist of NoticeDetails class. And pass the arraylist to the Adapter instead of the string array.